# Multiple vimrc files for different file types in vim?

Tags: vimrc, filetype

I'm a vim beginner. I want to handle multiple programming languages. I find great resources for how to perfect vim for one programming language by putting ton of stuff in one vimrc file. This is annoying.

I found about filetype plugin, but it's confusing. All I need is to put a vimrc file that runs for this specific lanuage. However, filetype plugin is huge with tons of features and tons of strange file paths.

**How do I set different settings/plugins for different file types?**

**Note:** It would be nice if there's a guide on how do people go about this basic need.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To enable filetype detection and plugins, add the following command to your `vimrc`:

```
filetype plugin on
```

Then, for each filetype you want settings for, create a Vimscript file in the following location:

```
~/.vim/after/ftplugin/
```

Name the file with the filetype you want it to apply to, so for e.g. a Python settings file, create:

```
~/.vim/after/ftplugin/python.vim
```

For more details, see [`:help ftplugin-overrule`](https://vimhelp.org/filetype.txt.html#ftplugin-overrule).

Comment: Thanks, this is great. However, I couldn't use vim-plug in this ***.vim file (probably it's not important).

Comment: @goonyMachine I'm a little surprised you can't use the `Plug` commands in this setup, but I don't know how vim-plug actually functions under-the-hood. If the filetype-specific plugin-loading is more important to you than vim-plug's management features, you could possibly switch over to Vim's `packages` feature. If you install your plugins under the `opt` subdirectory then they can be loaded only when you want them with `:packadd`. See `:help packages` for more details.

Comment: I didn't know about this. However, I'd stick with plugins in my main .vimrc over this. Hopefully the plugin is good enough to not do any overhead.

Comment: Additional info that might help beginners: 
(1) Vim uses certain names for different files (python.vim, cpp.vim) to get this name use :set FileType?
(2) For Latex users: vim sometimes assume .tex file as plain text file. to change this add the following to .vimrc
 let g:tex_flavor = "latex"

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes is good to define an autocmd just for your file type. You can put it in your `.vimrc`.

For example,

```
autocmd filetype tex nmap <buffer> K <leader>lv
```

`K` is mainly for documentation. But in tex files I want it to trigger to go line(vimtex).

Basically, you can type any ex cmd instead of nmap.

Comment: `:h autocmd` is recommended